# Site SSL leads to different directory

Tags: ssl

I have enabled SSL on my site. My problem is that https leads to a different directory. Directory should be same for SSL. I am using Parallel Plesk and not much aware about it. Can you please help to solve this issue.

Comment: What is your hosting company?

Answer (score 0):

Some hosting companies give you SSL, but it has it's own directory. It is expected that you'd put any pages that require SSL in that directory.

It's not the best setup, but it looks like you've got that arrangement.

Comment: I want to share the directory and my site is on  vps with
Parallels Plesk Panel

Comment: What do you mean share the directory?

Comment: I want to use same directory for https and https

Comment: I've never used unoeuro but you'll probably have to change your hosting package to something more sophisticated.